# Can I win as black here?

Tags: analysis, endgame

In the below position, I'm playing as Black and it's my turn.

```
[FEN "8/8/1K6/2P5/1P6/8/8/6kq b - - 0 1"]
```

I've recently gotten back into chess, and this one is driving me crazy. I can't seem to figure a way to win, only draw.  I don't appear to be able to get my king close enough. Can I win as Black? Any ideas would be great!

Comment: It is unclear to me which way the pawns are moving. Is white King on g3 or b6?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is really an easy win.

The first move is 1...Qe4; 2.Kg4 Kc7, and note that white cannot make any progress without losing one of the pawns, leaving an easy win since your Q can get to g8 after winning the first pawn.

```
[FEN "qk6/8/8/6P1/5P2/6K1/8/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Qe4 2. Kg4 Kc7
```

This is with it going the other way. It is harder, no question, but the first thing is to get the queen in front of the pawns.

```
 [FEN "8/8/1K6/2P5/1P6/8/8/6kq b - - 0 0"]

 1... Qa8 2. c6 Qb8+ 3. Kc5 Kf2 4. b5 Ke3 5. b6 Qe5+ 6. Kc4 Qa5 7. c7 Qa6+ 8. Kd5 Qb7+ 9. Kd6 Kd4 10. Kd7 Kc5 11. Kd8 Qxb6
```

Comment: Ok, but white moves pawn to g4, not king - am I missing something here?! It's been a while admittedly haha

Comment: Yes, what you are missing is that the original diagram would be read with white pushing the other way. I will add another diagram.

Comment: Ahh, yes, haha! Guess it's not clear given the position of the kings - still cant win this one yet!

Comment: Since most diagrams are read with white at the bottom, that is why I figured it was the first position. It is relatively rare for the diagrams to be shown from the black side.